# Not displaying some attributes in references?

Tags: biblatex, sharelatex

I'm new to (share)latex and I'm having some trouble styling my references. 
This is the bibtex code for a reference:

```
@article{bulling_tutorial_2014,
    title = {A {Tutorial} on {Human} {Activity} {Recognition} {Using} {Body}-worn {Inertial} {Sensors}},
    volume = {46},
    issn = {0360-0300},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2499621},
    doi = {10.1145/2499621},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2018-03-03},
    journal = {ACM Comput. Surv.},
    author = {Bulling, Andreas and Blanke, Ulf and Schiele, Bernt},
    month = jan,
    year = {2014},
    keywords = {gesture recognition, Activity recognition, Activity Recognition Chain (ARC), on-body inertial sensors},
    pages = {33:1--33:33}
}
```

As you can see, it contains a lot of attributes. To show my bibliography, I do the following in my tex document:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../shared/bibliography.bib}

%\begn{document} and the rest of the document

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={References}
]
```

[image: In my generated pdf, it looks like this]

Now my problem is that I don't want to have the ISSN number in the pdf, how do I exclude this element? I don't want to remove it from the bibtex code, maybe I need it later. Also, is it possible to remove, let say the ISBN number from all references except books? How can I create rules like these? I also just want the first letter of authors name to show up in the pdf, so the in the image, it should say A. Bulling instead of Andreas Bulling.

Comment: You can get initials only with the option `giveninits=true`. The option `isbn=false` suppresses all ISBNs and ISSNs. If you want more fine-grained control, you can use `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\clearfield`, or `\DeclareSourcemap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get name initials with

```
giveninits=true
```

You can suppress all ISBNs and ISSNs at the same time with the option

```
isbn=false
```

For more fine-grained control you could use something like

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
```

or

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=issn, null]
    }
  }
}
```

to get rid of all ISSNs.

Or even

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {}
    {\clearfield{isbn}}}
```

or

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=issn, null]
    }
    \map{
      \pernottype{book}
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
    }
  }
}
```

to delete ISBNs only for all entries but `@book`s.

There is also `pertype` instead of `\pernottype` to reverse the logic here and let a map apply only to entries of a particular type.

While the `\AtEveryBibitem` method with `\clearfield` might be more convenient, I believe that the sourcemapping is conceptually nicer, since the latter removes the field at an earlier stage. This can become important if you want to suppress a field that interacts with label generation or uniqueness features.